# How to remove only the immediate parent p tag

Tags: jquery

I'm using a rich text editor (ckeditor) which wraps everything in `<p>` tags, even images. So when I insert an image it does this:

```
<div id="description">
    <p>Some introduction the user wrote</p>
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
    <p>Some text here that the user wrote</p>
    <p>Oops an inline image <img src="/path/to/image" /></p>
    <p>More stuff that the user wrote.</p>
</div>
```

I just want to remove the wrapping `<p>` tag on all images that are within the `#description` div.

I tried `$('img').unwrap()` but it stripped all the `<p>` tags.

I also tried `$('img').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });` which removed the entire image from the DOM.

Any ideas how to do it? A JSFiddle would be really appreciated if you manage to get it working.

Comment: A typo I'm sure, but your `div` start tag is incomplete (missing `>`)

Comment: Unwrap should work just fine.  I don't see any way it could possibly remove all `p` tags:  http://jsfiddle.net/d7md9rgd/

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achieve?  When `$('img').unwrap()`  is called then the result will be:  `....<p>Some text here that the user wrote</p><img src="/path/to/image"><p>More stuff that the user wrote.</p>...` so whats wrong about that?

Comment: Added the fiddle too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#description p img").unwrap();

});
```

Comment: This would `unwrap` the parent `p` tag which would remove the `div` not the `p`.

Comment: This would work though the `each` is now unnecessary and could just be `$("#description p img").unwrap()`.

Comment: Yes, I did that only.

Comment: I just want to remove the wrapping <p> tag on all images that are within the #description div. What he tried `$("img").unwrap()` will unwrap all `<img...` tags. @roshan

Comment: Nice observation ! @void . I wonder why $("img").unwrap() stripped all p tags for OP. Even the wrong mark up won't do that.

Comment: I updated my question code slightly. Running this solution removes the all the `<p>` tags because some `<img>` tags are not within `<p>` tags. But some are. Its only the ones where it is in a `<p>` that I need to 'cut' out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$('img').each(function (){
    var $img = $(this);
    var $p = $img.parent('p');
    if($p.val() != undefined)
    {
        $p.replaceWith($img);
    }
});
```

I have added a check for parent tag here. So, if it is `'p'`, then only it shall be replaced with `'img'` below it. If what you want are the entire content under `'p'`, then replace the last line by this -

```
$p.replaceWith($p.html());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7snLne2/